# How to determine the Green’s function of $y''=f(x)$ with the boundary conditions: $y(0)=0$, $y'(1)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, greens-function

I want to determine the Green’s functions of the following BVP:

Let $y''=f(x)$ with the boundary conditions: $y(0)=0$, $y'(1)=0$

So the homogeneous solution for this is: $y_h(x)=C_1+C_2x$,  has the fundamental system $ \{u_1(x),u_2(x)\}=\{1,x\}$

Now I'm stuck here, I want to determine the new FS $\{v_1(x),v_2(x)\}$:

the first boundary conditions gives us:

$y(0)=0 \Rightarrow C_1+C_2.0=0\Rightarrow C_1=0 \Rightarrow v_1(x)=x$

the second boundary conditions gives us:

$y'(1)=0 \Rightarrow C_2=0  \Rightarrow v_2(x)=1$

Hence $\{v_1(x),v_2(x)\}=\{x,1\}$ and furthermore satisfy the boudary conditions $v_1(0)=0,v'_2(1)=0 $ and we can easly show the Wronskian determinant $W(x)=-1$ is that correct? I think it should be different from  $ \{u_1(x),u_2(x)\}=\{1,x\}$.

And I don't know how to continue this to find the green's function.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You need to solve the problem $L(G) = G'' = \delta(x-\xi)$, with $G(0) = G'(1) = 0$, and $0<\xi<1$, where $G$ is the Green's function corresponding to the linear operator $L$ and given boundary conditions.

Comment: @Dmoreno and I don't know if my new FS are correct or no!

Comment: @Dmoreno yes I did that, but i was stuck there, can you please write it to me?

Comment: Ok, just give me a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking it up on my comment, the Green's function associated to the problem $L(y) = y'' = f$, $y(0)=y'(0)=0$ is given by the solution to $L(G)=G''=\delta(x-\xi)$, $G(0) = G'(1) =0$, with $0<\xi<1$. One can apply integration by parts to show that $y(\xi) = \int^1_0 f(x) G(x;\xi)\,\mathrm{d}x$.

The task at hand is then to integrate $G''=\delta(x-\xi)$. Integrate once with respect to $x$ to have:

$$\int^{0}_{G'} \mathrm{d}G' = \int^1_x \delta(x-\xi)\,\mathrm{d}x \implies G' = H(x-\xi) - 1,$$

where $H$ is the Heaviside (or unit step) function. Note that the BC $G'(1)=0$ has been imposed. Integrate once more to find

$$\int^G_0 \,\mathrm{d}G = \int^x_0 \left[ H(x-\xi) -1 \right]\,\mathrm{d}x \implies G(x;\xi) = (x-\xi)H(x-\xi) - x,$$

where the BC $G(0)=0$ has been imposed.

I have checked that indeed this is the Green's function to the problem for the particular case $f(x) = x$, with the help of Mathematica.

I hope you find this useful.

Comment: emm I see, Thank you !

Comment: Hi @Joel, happy to help! Would you consider accepting this answer?

Comment: Hi! yes, sure :)